# Hibernate ColumnTransformer but with input

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I have a Postgres entity that has encrypted data and I would like to know if there is an easy way of mapping the encrypted bytea column to a string/number field. The catch here is that the encrypted key is stored in a hashicorp vault and is fetched via rest so I can't just use a hibernate `ColumnTransformer` with a built in postgres encrypting function because it will not take in any dynamic input into the annotation.

Is there a way to do this? Or are my only options
1) do the encryption on the server and save already encrypted data
2) make all the DB queries native queries and use postgres `encrypt/decrypt` functions (which means I can't use JpaRepository::save for example)

In some placed I will need to use the postgres `decrypt` function because this sensitive data is crucial data for reports so I wanted to avoid having server side logic for encryption and decryption.